# 'xmlParseEntityRef: no name' warnings while loading xml into a php file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am reading an xml in php using `simplexml_load_file`. However while trying to load the xml it displays a list of warnings

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <project orderno="6" campaign_name="International Relief & Development" project in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3    
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3    
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://..../index.php/site/projects/:15: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ional Relief & Development" project_id="313" client_name="International Relief & in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3    
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3    
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://..../index.php/site/projects/:15: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /home/bluecard1/public_html/test.php on line 3
```

How do I rectify to remove these warnings?

*(XML is generated from url `http://..../index.php/site/projects` & loaded into  a variable in the test.php. I dont have write priveleges to index.php)*

Comment: The XML is invalid. You might not be able to load it at all. Errors can be suppressed by adding `@` in front of `simplexml_load_file` or by adding a flag, see the manual page of `simplexml_load_file` for more information and please delete your question, it's a duplicate.

Comment: I can see that my answer is getting quite a lot of attention, if that's actually the solution: can you please flag it as "correct answer"? thanks.

Answer (score 181):

The XML is most probably invalid.
The problem could be the "&"

```
$text = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $text);
```

will get rid of the "&" and replace it with HTML code version... give it a try.

Comment: The best practice while working with XML is to ensure there are no conflicting characters and you should replace them before parsin

Comment: thanks, main point of this question is because xml is invalid

Comment: global search is implicit in preg_replace. If you add 'g' at the end you got a warning : Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Don't add 'g' at the end. It cause warning - preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'. Please edit the original answer back.

Comment: You can now use `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);`. See https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#output-escaping

Comment: thanks, setOutputEscapingEnable works beautifully, save time instead of manually escaping each value.

Answer (score 98):

Found this [here ...](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/resolution-xmlparseentityref-noname-xml-error/)

> **Problem:** An XML parser returns the error “xmlParseEntityRef: noname”
>
> **Cause:** There is a stray ‘&’ (ampersand character) somewhere in the XML text eg. some text & some more text
>
> **Solution:**
>
> - Solution 1: Remove the ampersand.
> - Solution 2: Encode the ampersand    (that is replace the `&` character with `&amp;` ). Remember to Decode    when reading the XML
>     text.
> - Solution 3: Use CDATA sections (text    inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.) eg.    <![CDATA[some text & some more
>     text]]>
>
> Note: ‘&’ ‘<' '>‘ will all give problems if not handled correctly.

Comment: Do we know why this is? Also, will a CDATA section still be picked up by a browser that would render some of this data? I have some HTML tags inside my XML tags and I need them to be rendered to the end user for an editing tool.

Answer (score 14):

Try to clean the HTML first using this function:

```
$html = htmlspecialchars($html);
```

Special chars are usually represented differently in HTML and it might be confusing for the compiler. Like `&` becomes `&amp;`.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is downvoted? `htmlspecialchars()` is the precise function to convert `&, ", <, >` chars in the element data.

Comment: This answer is downvoted cause it doesn't work well in this case. Using that function will totally break your XML by converting "<" to "&lt;". I'm unaware of any way that you can use `htmlspecialchars()` and not break XML. I tried a few flags and my XML still broke.

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` on the content of an xml tag, not on the whole XML

Comment: This answer helps me a lot. And yes, as @gbalduzzi said: Only use it to the content.

Answer (score 9):

I use a combined version :

```
strip_tags(preg_replace("/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/", "&amp;",$textorhtml))
```

Comment: This one is working perfectly. You're just missing the ending right bracket

Answer (score 9):

> **PROBLEM**

- PHP function `simplexml_load_file` is throwing parsing error `parser
  error : xmlParseEntityRef` while trying to load the XML file from a URL.

> **CAUSE**

- XML returned by the URL is not a valid XML. It contains **`&`** value
  instead of **`&amp;`**. It is quite possible that there are other errors which aren't obvious at this point of time.

> **THINGS OUT OF OUR CONTROL**

- Ideally, we should make sure that a valid XML is feed into PHP `simplexml_load_file` function, but it looks like we don't have any control over how the XML is created.
- It is also not possible to force `simplexml_load_file` to process an
  invalid XML file. It does not leave us with many options, other than
  fixing the XML file itself.

> **POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Convert Invalid XML to Valid XML. It can be done using **`PHP tidy extension`**. Further instructions can be found from http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Once you are sure that the extension exists or is installed, please do the following.

```
/**
 * As per the question asked, the URL is loaded into a variable first, 
 * which we can assume to be $xml
 */
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project orderno="6" campaign_name="International Relief & Development for under developed nations">
    <invalid-data>Some other data containing & in it</invalid-data>
    <unclosed-tag>
</project>
XML;

/**
 * Whenever we use tidy it is best to pass some configuration options 
 * similar to $tidyConfig. In this particular case we are making sure that
 * tidy understands that our input and output is XML.
 */
$tidyConfig = array (
    'indent' => true,
    'input-xml' => true, 
    'output-xml' => true,
    'wrap' => 200
);

/**
 * Now we can use tidy to parse the string and then repair it.
 */
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($xml, $tidyConfig, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

/**
 * If we try to output the repaired XML string by echoing $tidy it should look like. 

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <project orderno="6" campaign_name="International Relief &amp; Development for under developed nations">
      <invalid-data>Some other data containing &amp; in it</invalid-data>
      <unclosed-tag></unclosed-tag>
 </project> 

 * As you can see that & is now fixed in campaign_name attribute 
 * and also with-in invalid-data element. You can also see that the   
 * <unclosed-tag> which didn't had a close tag, has been fixed too.
 */
echo $tidy;

/**
 * Now when we try to use simplexml_load_string to load the clean XML. When we
 * try to print_r it should look something like below.

 SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [orderno] => 6
            [campaign_name] => International Relief & Development for under developed nations
        )

    [invalid-data] => Some other data containing & in it
    [unclosed-tag] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)

 */
 $simpleXmlElement = simplexml_load_string($tidy);
 print_r($simpleXmlElement);
```

> **CAUTION**

The developer should try to compare the invalid XML with a valid XML (generated by tidy), to see there are no adverse side effects after using tidy. Tidy does an extremely good job of doing it correctly, but it never hurts to see it visually and to be 100% sure. In our case it should be as simple as comparing $xml with $tidy.

Answer (score 7):

The XML is invalid.

```
<![CDATA[ 
{INVALID XML}
]]>
```

CDATA should be wrapped around all special XML characters, as per [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#sec-cdata-sect)

Answer (score 3):

This is in deed due to characters messing around with the data. Using `htmlentities($yourText)` worked for me (I had html code inside the xml document). See https://www.php.net/htmlentities.

Answer (score 2):

This solve my problème:

```
$description = strip_tags($value['Description']);
$description=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $description);
$description= preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $description);
$description=str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', html_entity_decode((htmlspecialchars_decode($description))));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this issue with opencart try editing

> catalog/controller/extension/feed/google_sitemap.php
>   For More info and How to do it refer this: [xmlparseentityref-no-name-error](http://allhtaccess.info/opencart-xmlparseentityref-no-name-error/)