# PHP XML error on line 16 at column 6: xmlParsePI : no target name after upgrade apache php

Tags: php, xml, apache, .htaccess

Hello please anyone can help me to solve this problem, this error occur after upgrade apache php

**PHP XML error on line 16 at column 6: xmlParsePI : no target name**,

Fyi, i am used sitemap.php page then set RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml?$ sitemap.php. 
Below is my sitemap.php code

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset  xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">'; 
include "config.php";
include "dbclass.php";
include "classes.php";
include "fgeneral.php";
$mydb = new myDBC();
//HOME
$result = $mydb->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `homepage`");
$row = $mydb->runFetchArray($result);
$date = $row["date"]; //the date stored
$year = substr($date,0,4); //work out the year
$mon  = substr($date,5,2); //work out the month
$day  = substr($date,8,2); //work out the day
$displaydate = ''.$year.'-'.$mon.'-'.$day.'';
?>
<url>  
<loc><?=ROOT_URL?></loc>  
<lastmod><?=$displaydate?></lastmod>  
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>  
<priority>1.00</priority>  
</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, i found solution here
    ['xmlParseEntityRef: no name' warnings while loading xml into a php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604436/xmlparseentityref-no-name-warnings-while-loading-xml-into-a-php-file)
and 
    http://www.stevenmarkford.com/resolution-xmlparseentityref-noname-xml-error/