# XML Load File Error

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I installed a script and when I login to admin dashboard am getting this error:

> Warning (2): simplexml_load_file(): /app/Plugin/PaypalAdaptive/info.xml:7: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name [APP/Controller/PluginsController.php, line 1151]

I checked the file `pluginscontroller.php` and this is the code. I copied from part of the entire file.

Line 1151 is: `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);`

Full code starts here:

```
        // get all installed plugins
        $plugins = $this->Plugin->find( 'all', array(
            'order' => 'id DESC'
        ));

        $totalNewVersion = 0;
        if($plugins != null)
        {
            foreach($plugins as $k => $plugin)
            {
                $plugin = $plugin['Plugin'];
                $file = sprintf(PLUGIN_INFO_PATH, $plugin['key']);
                if(file_exists($file))
                {
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
                    if($xml != null && isset($xml->version))
                    {
                        if((string)$xml->version > $plugin['version'])
                        {
                            $totalNewVersion += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $totalNewVersion;
    }

    public function admin_do_upgrade( $id )
    {
        if(!$this->Plugin->hasAny(array('id' => $id)))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('This plugin does not exist'), 'default', array('class' => 'Metronic-alerts alert alert-danger fade in' ));
        }
        else 
        {
```

Comment: Please show a minimal XML file that generates this error when read in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['xmlParseEntityRef: no name' warnings while loading xml into a php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604436/xmlparseentityref-no-name-warnings-while-loading-xml-into-a-php-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you the XML is invalid, probably because it contains an "&" character that should have been escaped as `&amp;`.

Do what you would do with any faulty goods - send it back to the supplier and tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, I had made some edits in the code and used `"&"` instead of `"&amp;"` thats what caused the problem.