# plyr's ldply changes read_xml's behavior

Tags: r, xml, plyr

I'm trying to read just a couple of fields from each of a bunch of xml files. I wrote a little function that extracts the fields I need and returns them as a vector:

```
id_dir <- function(d) {
  xml <- read_xml(d)
  id <- xml_text(xml_node(xml, 'AwardID'))
  dir <- xml_text(xml_node(xml, 'Abbreviation'))
  phone <- xml_text(xml_node(xml, 'PhoneNumber'))
  return(c(id, phone, dir))
}
```

But when I wrap it with `ldply` the following happens:

```
setwd('xmls/2017')
files <- list.files()[1:100]
sev_data <- plyr::ldply(files, id_dir)
```

`Error in read_xml.character(d) : xmlParseEntityRef: no name [68]`

This happens despite the fact that the following code works as intended:

```
id_dir(glue('xmls/2017/{files[1]}'))
```

`"1700003"    "5746317432" "MPS"`

I've tried poking around SO for quite a while now, but mostly I'm seeing people talking about PHP and stuff that is most likely irrelevant.

For reproducibility [here](https://github.com/jdollman/stackoverflow/blob/data/1700229.xml) are a [couple](https://github.com/jdollman/stackoverflow/blob/data/1715157.xml) of files I'm reading in.

Comment: [The error suggests that at least one of the XML files is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604436/xmlparseentityref-no-name-warnings-while-loading-xml-into-a-php-file), likely due to ampersand characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works as expected which can be verified with the examples you have shared.

```
id_dir('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdollman/stackoverflow/data/1700229.xml')
#[1] "1700229"    "8659743466" "MPS" 
      
id_dir('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdollman/stackoverflow/data/1715157.xml')
#[1] "1715157"    "5705773510" "BIO"
```

So the issue is how you are passing the files to function `id_dir`. I don't use `plyr` since it is long retired and replaced with `dplyr`. I would just use `lapply` here.

Another issue could be that you have other files in your directory which is not `xml`. You can specify in `list.files` to select only `'xml'` files. Try :

```
setwd('xmls/2017')
files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xml$')[1:100]
sev_data <- lapply(files, id_dir)
```