# Parsing XML with illegal special characters (&)

Tags: python, xml

I have thousands of XML files like follow

```
<names>
    <Id>1518845</Id>
    <Name>Confessions of a Thug (Paperback)</Name>
    <Authors>Philip Meadows Taylor</Authors>
    <Publisher>Rupa & Co</Publisher>
    <CountsOfReview>2.0</CountsOfReview>
</names>
```

I've tried the codes follow to parse

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("xm_file.xml")
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("xm_file.xml")
```

and

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.parse("xm_file.xml", parser=parser)
```

and all lead to one of those errors

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 10, column 18
```

```
XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 10, column 19
```

I searched and tried a lot for a solution for this to work to all files but in vain

NOTE : this didnt help me : [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml)

another situation is

```
<names>
    <Id>1481744</Id>
    <Name>Lettres de René-Édouard Claparède <1832-1871>.: Choisies et annotées</Name>
    <Authors>René-Édouard Claparède</Authors>
    <ISBN>3796505635</ISBN>
    <Rating>2.0</Rating>
    <PublishYear>1971</PublishYear>
    <PublishMonth>31</PublishMonth>
    <PublishDay>12</PublishDay>
</names>
```

while parsing it just handle the XML as if it is :

```
<names>
    <Id>1481744</Id>
    <Name>Lettres de René-Édouard Claparède</Name>
</names>
```

and other info doesnt appear

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604436/xmlparseentityref-no-name-warnings-while-loading-xml-into-a-php-file

Comment: This is python not PHP

Comment: But the solution is the same.

Comment: It’s not XML, Jim, at least not as we know it. Your question isn’t titled correctly - what you’re trying to parse *isn’t XML*

Comment: Its an XML with invalid format

Comment: No, it's ***not*** XML.   @barny is right.   You did not understand the duplicate link the last time you asked this exact question.   You cannot expect an XML parser, which is written based on following the rules that *define* XML, to succeed with arbitrary transgressions against those rules.

Comment: The `&` and `<` characters cannot appear in content without being escaped because those unescaped characters have special meaning in XML.   If you get textual data that you wish to repair to be XML, it's a hard problem to solve automatically.  Re-read the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085) for more details and for guidance on how to proceed.  ***Do not just keep repeating your post.***  Your case is covered there; it is not special.

Comment: You don't have thousands of XML files. You have thousands of non-XML files. In fact, you have a heap of junk.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the `&` before-hand:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """

<names>
    <Id>1518845</Id>
    <Name>Confessions of a Thug (Paperback)</Name>
    <Authors>Philip Meadows Taylor</Authors>
    <Publisher>Rupa & Co</Publisher>
    <CountsOfReview>2.0</CountsOfReview>
</names>

"""

data = data.replace('&', '&amp;')
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))

for publisher in tree.findall("Publisher"):
    print(publisher.text)
```

Which yields

```
Rupa & Co
```

---

A possible way would be to load the files in question before, replace the `&` and feed it to `xml.etree.ElementTree`, as in:

```
with open("some_cool_file") as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    content = content.replace('&', '&amp;')
    xml = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(content))
```

Comment: Please see my edit on question

Comment: Good try, but the OP added another test for you.

Comment: @Jan, replacing `&` like that is dangerous because there could be actual XML entities in the data that would then be mangled.  Yes, you could use a more complicated regex to catch many of them.  Anyway, this general topic of how to parse bad "XML" has already been much more thoroughly addressed in other Q/A.